# Why my code to find prime number from 2 to a given number in Javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript at the moment and have an exercise to solve. The exercise is given bellow:
**Output prime numbers**
An integer number greater than 1 is called a prime. if it cannot be divided without a
remainder by anything except 1 and itself.
In other words, n > 1 is a prime if it can’t be evenly divided by anything except 1 and n .
For example, 5 is a prime, because it cannot be divided without a remainder by 2 , 3 and 4 .
Write the code which outputs prime numbers in the interval from 2 to n .
For n = 10 the result will be 2,3,5,7 .
P.S. The code should work for any n , not be hard-tuned for any fixed value.

Now i try to solve it this way.

```
let n = 20;

outer:
for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        while (j>1 && j<i) {
            if (i%j == 0 ) {
                continue outer
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(i);

}
```

but it show wrong output

now i also can solve it in this way

```
let n = 20;
let result = 0;

outer:
for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i%j == 0) {
            continue outer
        }
    }
    console.log(i)
}
```

***Now I ask for your help to know that exactly in where I did mistake in 1st Salutation .***

Comment: I don't think we can help you without proposing some other algorithm. I don't really see any logic behind you algorithm

Comment: One obvious mistake: your outer loop starts at 4, so it can never find 2 or 3.

Comment: @radovix I added my salutation which work properly. But i need to find in where i did mistake in 1st code

Comment: Another one: your `while (j>1 && j<i) {` may be infinite because the variables in the condition never change

Comment: @Bergi Can you please explain further, why `while (j>1 && j<i) { ` create an  infinite loop ?
Because as fur as i can understand, that the value of i and j is change according to every for loop iteration . Can you please help me here ?

Comment: @smrakib Nothing in `while (j>1 && j<i)`, `if (i%j == 0)` or `continue outer` does change the values of `i` or `j`.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks a lot, now i got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if `if (i%j == 0 )` is `false` you remain in the `while` without changing the variables so you are infinite stuck there.

You could add another label for the inner `for` and either go to the one or the other

```js
let n = 20;

outer: for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    inner: for (let j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        while (j>1 && j<i) {
            if (i%j == 0 ) {
                continue outer;
            } else {
              continue inner;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(i);

}
```

Comment: No. The correct solution is to just drop the `while` loop, or make it an `if` statement.

Comment: @Bergi Indeed, but the OP already had posted that solution in their question. They were asking what was wrong with this version.

Comment: Still, converting the `while` to an `if` is a better solution than putting a `continue` in the else branch.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks for your comment but@Gabriele Petrioli is right about his ans. I already have salutations about prime number problem. But i was tryout different way to solve it and then suddenly face that given `infinite` `while loop` problem. Then i post this question where the main purpose was to find out why my logic not working. So the purpose was to find out which wrong logic i made (Its impotent, because currently i am in learning process) rather then the optimal salutation (Which i already had) of the prime number problem. You both are very helpful and many many thanks for your support.

Comment: @Bergi, As you are taking about this salutation as it's the optimal one
```let n = 20;

outer:for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
 for (let j = 1; j < n; j++) {
  if (j>1 && j<i) {
   if (i%j == 0) {
    continue outer
   }
  }
 }
console.log(i);
}```

Comment: @smrakib Yes, that snippet with `if (j>1 && j<i)` is the natural solution to the problem of the infinite `while` loop. You don't want to always `break` (or `continue inner`) from it, you just don't want a loop at all but only the condition. Then, the next logical step would be to integrate this range restriction into the `for` loop directly, arriving at the solution that you already have.